# error shows in logcat No adaper skipping layout while setting firebase data to my User_chat Activity recyclerview adapter android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

error shows in logcat No adaper skipping layout while setting firebase data to  my User_chat Activity recyclerview adapter android it will  not open

```
                recyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.chat_recycle);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(User_Chating.this));
                SendSendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        SendMessage();
                    }
                });
                adapter=new MessageAdapter(User_Chating.this,messagesList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
                    private void FetchMethod() {
                rootref.child("Messages").child(Message_Sender_Id).child(MessegeReceverId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        ChatMessages chatMessages=dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessages.class);
                        messagesList.add(chatMessages);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

Comment: where you call FetchMethod() ??

Comment: i called it after that line adapter=new MessageAdapter(User_Chating.this,messagesList);